# Inconveniente para abrir archivo c# dentro de Visual Studio Code 2022

Tags: c#, asp.net

Cordial saludo equipo espero se encuentren bien, necesito pedirles el favor con lo siguiente, tengo lo siguiente con un archivo con nombre Existencias Total  (Dentro del proyecto que tiene la empresa tiene como nombre: ReportInventarioExistencias.cs, señalado con el numero 1)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al momento de dar clic en donde aparece Resultados de la Búsqueda dentro del formulario Existencia Total, se debe de desplegar un seleccionador de columnas como aparece señalado con el número 3 en la imagen.
El código que tienen en la compañía es el siguiente:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Ziur.UI.Win.Forms.Reports
{
    public partial class ReportInventarioExistencias : Ziur.UI.Win.Forms.Reports.ReportInventarioLotes
    {
        public ReportInventarioExistencias() :
            base(1, false, 500)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            General.AddColumnValidateEmail(gridBuscar, true);
        }

        private void gridBuscar_InitializeLayout(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.InitializeLayoutEventArgs e)
        {
    e.Layout.Bands[0].SortedColumns.Add("NomInvCompleto", false, true);
    e.Layout.GroupByBox.Hidden = true;
    e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns["CodLote"].Hidden = false; 
    e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns["CodLote"].ExcludeFromColumnChooser = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ExcludeFromColumnChooser.True;
  e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns["NomLote"].ExcludeFromColumnChooser = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ExcludeFromColumnChooser.True;
        }

        protected internal override void ConvertEnterInTab(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            base.ConvertEnterInTab(sender, e);
        }

        private void ClickControls(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!General.enPropUsuario)
                return;

            base.propiedadesControlesPorUsuario(sender);
        }
    }
}
```

Necesito saber cómo podría ver como abrir la lista desplegable teniendo en cuenta el código que comienza con la instrucción  e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns , código que interpreto utilizaron la herramienta Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.InitializeLayoutEventArgs e

Agradezco cualquier colaboración con este inconveniente.

Answer (score 1):

creo que mas bien te conviene revisar que se hace cuando presionas el boton buscar

Comment: Hola amigo muchas gracias, escarbando el código en ReportInventarioExistencias.Designer.cs, incluí lo siguiente:

Comment: Cordial saludo @Leonardo Lazcano, le envío en el siguiente enlace el código del botón buscar 
https://github.com/hecamava/Bot-ndeaperturaReq5407/blob/main/Codigo   se observa que hay una función con nombre  "NomInvCompleto", la cual he buscado       en todo el código y pese a eso no logro traer los registros al formulario, saludos!.